# Indy TIdSMTPRelay and timeout

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-2006

We use TIdSMTPRelay to relay some messages. Sometimes the receiving email server will hang and just keep the connection open and our relayer never times out. Is there a way of giving it e.g. 5 mins to deliver the message and then give up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdSMTPRelay` has `ConnectTimeout` and `ReadTimeout` properties.  Indy does not have a `SendTimeout` property, so if the hang is occurring during a send rather than a connect/read, the only option would be to manually assign an `SO_SNDTIMEO` timeout on the underlying socket itself, such as by using the `Socket.Binding.SetSocketOption()` method in the `OnConnect` event.